# Jackson's JsonNode implementation in Gson

Tags: android, serialization, jackson, gson

I am currently converting Jackson implementations to Gson because of dex size.

I am wondering what is the Gson equivalent of

```
    public void setNortheast(JsonNode northeast) {
        LatLng northBound = new LatLng(northeast.get("lat").asDouble(), northeast.get("lng").asDouble());
        this.northeast = northBound;
    }
```

I have written:

```
public void setNortheast(JsonObject northeast) {
    LatLng northBound = null;
    try {
        northBound = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(northeast.getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(northeast.getString("lng")));
    } catch(JsonException e) {
    }
    this.northeast = northBound;
}
```

But, it does not seem to work. Have I written  a correct code?

Thanks in Advance! :D

Comment: What are you getting? Have you confirmed that the parameter `JsonObject northeast` is set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use getDouble instead of Double.parseDouble( "String "  )

northeast.getDouble("lat")

northeast.getDouble("lng")

Modified Code as below,

```
public void setNortheast(JsonObject northeast) {
    LatLng northBound = null;
    try {
        northBound = new LatLng(northeast.getDouble("lat"), northeast.getDouble("lng"));
    } catch(JsonException e) {
    }
    this.northeast = northBound;
}
```

Reference: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html